# Query cache in JPA 2.1 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, orm

The Hibernate has two level cache and Query cache. But as I know in JPA there are only two level cache. Also in other ORMs I saw Query cache. Maybe I'm somewhere wrong. Therefore, I want to ask you. 
What about Query cache? Is this a feature of some ORMs or is it in JPA? And if it's in JPA, then where?

Comment: Why not look at the JPA spec and see if it even mentions a query cache?

Answer (score 0):

**The second level cache is an application level cache it will store entity data....**

**Query cache is separate cache that stores query results only...**

The two caches mostley go together...

The two caches provide improved performance in a transparent way by reducing number of sql statements hits to the database.

Before retrieval from query cache , cached entity identifiers are used to access the second level cache...

If second level cache contains data for given id , it returns it , if not sql query is issued to load the entity from the database.

**The query cache is looks like hashmap where key is composed by query text and parameter values and the value is a list of entity id's that match the query...**

```
["From Student where firstName = ?", ["Balram"]].  --> [1,2]]
```

Some queries don't return entities , instead they return only premitive values ...

In those cases the values them selves will be stored in the query cache ....

Refer this link to understand ....

["Level Cache and Query Cache"](https://dzone.com/articles/pitfalls-hibernate-second-0)

Comment: Thanks. But I knew it. I want to know could the Second-level cache exist without Query-cache. And also I want to know there are in JPA specification Query-cache or not. Because in JPA specification i can find only the First-level-cache and the Second-level-cache.